# Insert a value dynamically from one array to another in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I have seen some answers on stackoverflow how to do it but it does not satisfy what I need.
So I have a master array in php with all the user values,I have given the user to select the option of which value they want to select and then I echo out those values from the master array.
I want an array ,which will take those values from the master array, that will match the id which I have used to select the choices. eg if id =25 it should take the values from the row of master array having id value =25.

Note:I have taken id values as array .like[16,18,23] it can be anything between 15 and 26.

```
array(

    array('id' => '15', 'title' => 'product5', 'brand_name' => 'brand5', 'price' => '1233'),
    array('id' => '16', 'title' => 'product4', 'brand_name' => 'brand4', 'price' => '1234'),
    array('id' => '17','title' => 'produc23', 'brand_name' => 'brand3', 'price' => '2222'),
    array('id' => '18','title' => 'produc2', 'brand_name' => 'brand2', 'price' => '455'),
    array('id' => '19', 'title' => "vivek's 1st product", 'brand_name' => 'vivek', 'price' => '1000'),
    array('id' => '20', 'title' => 'Slik Shirt', 'brand_name' => 'Ramraj', 'price' => '599'),
    array('id' => '21', 'title' => 'Bhagalpuri Kota Silk Saree', 'brand_name' => 'Vimalnath Synthetics', 'price' => '1299'),
    array('id' => '22', 'title' => 'fsdf', 'brand_name' => 'fsdf', 'price' => '200',),
    array('id' => '23', 'title' => 'wdw', 'brand_name' => 'qwqewq', 'price' => '2000'),
    array('id' => '24', 'title' => 'productawesome', 'brand_name' => 'awesome', 'price' => '1000'),
    array('id' => '25',  'title' => 'redmi 5A', 'brand_name' => 'redmi', 'price' => '6000'),
    array('id' => '26', 'title' => 'naruto_stickers', 'brand_name' => 'anime', 'price' => '200')
    )
```

If someone finds the answer ,please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming your id is $id. And master array is assigned to $master. You can loop through and check against id.

```
$row = -1;
For($x =0; $x < count($master); $x++){
 If($master[$x]['id'] === $id){
   $row = $master[$x];
   break;
 }
}
//if row == -1 no match
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try array_filter() and in_array() like below

```
$master= array(

    array('id' => '15', 'title' => 'product5', 'brand_name' => 'brand5', 'price' => '1233'),
    array('id' => '16', 'title' => 'product4', 'brand_name' => 'brand4', 'price' => '1234'),
    array('id' => '17','title' => 'produc23', 'brand_name' => 'brand3', 'price' => '2222'),
    array('id' => '18','title' => 'produc2', 'brand_name' => 'brand2', 'price' => '455'),
    array('id' => '19', 'title' => "vivek's 1st product", 'brand_name' => 'vivek', 'price' => '1000'),
    array('id' => '20', 'title' => 'Slik Shirt', 'brand_name' => 'Ramraj', 'price' => '599'),
    array('id' => '21', 'title' => 'Bhagalpuri Kota Silk Saree', 'brand_name' => 'Vimalnath Synthetics', 'price' => '1299'),
    array('id' => '22', 'title' => 'fsdf', 'brand_name' => 'fsdf', 'price' => '200',),
    array('id' => '23', 'title' => 'wdw', 'brand_name' => 'qwqewq', 'price' => '2000'),
    array('id' => '24', 'title' => 'productawesome', 'brand_name' => 'awesome', 'price' => '1000'),
    array('id' => '25',  'title' => 'redmi 5A', 'brand_name' => 'redmi', 'price' => '6000'),
    array('id' => '26', 'title' => 'naruto_stickers', 'brand_name' => 'anime', 'price' => '200')
    );

    $selected  = array(15,18);
    print_r(array_filter($master,function($arr) use ($selected){
      return in_array($arr['id'],$selected);
    }));
```